# How to update the weights of a Tensorflow.js model?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow.js

I currently have a tensorflow.js convolutional neural network model that detects if certain images are happy or sad (based on facial expression). This is done through the browser with the user uploading an image of a face or using the webcam which the model then determines the outcome for. However, the user also has the option to override this result if the model predicts incorrectly.

What I am planning to do is have the model retrain with the user uploaded image if the user decides to override the result. I understand this can be done with model.fit and then model.save functions within the tensorflow.js API.

My concern is that the model weights are currently stored in a google cloud storage bucket but I am unsure how to update the files in order to reuse the updated weights the next time a user passes in a face. Is there a certain way I can do it using google cloud or another similar cloud storage without having to change the model.load link every time?

I know that this is a rather vague problem but I don't have access to an indexeddb so cloud storage seems to be the best option for storing the weights for the browser to access and update. I am just not sure how to save the model without changing the link from which it should be accessed through model.load at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data of the objects within the Cloud Storage bucket by [setting up Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning). Only thing is that if you want to access a previous version of the object, you would have to use the generation number, like this:

```
gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]#[GENERATION_NUMBER]
```